# How to reference "top-most" view?

Tags: ios, uiview, hierarchy

In `iOS`, programmatically, how can one find what **top most** `UIView` is?

In other words .. what view is displayed right now?

Say, i have a nib with 3 views stacked on top of one another. Inside a program, i can remove the top view if I know what it is. How can i find out what view is on top of the nib?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have a lot of top most views because a view doesn't have to take all the screen.

If you want the top most subview of a view, you can call

```
[yourView subviews];
```

and take tje last one (they are in displayed order, most front last)

```
[[yourView subviews] objectAtIndex:[[yourView subviews] count]];
```

edit: this is better (from comments)

```
[[yourView subviews] lastObject];
```

If you know your displayed viewController just replace yourView by yourController.view

Comment: Don't forget to test for isHidden. And .alpha != 0. And that the view is on-screen.

Comment: in your example, how do i know what `yourView` is?

Comment: As I said in my last sentence, yourView can be yourMainViewController.view if yourMainViewController is the controller thats handles the displayed views (for instance your rootViewController if you didn't add any modalViewController or didn't pushed any controller in a navigation controller).

More generally, it is the first view you have that you know is currently displayed.

If you want a more precise answer you'll need to explain what your application is and what it is displaying, and I might be able to tell you what view you have to use.

Comment: PS just use "lastObject" in that objC there

Comment: Also you can use HitTest. This method will return an object of virtual touch.

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
UIView *topMost = [[self.view subviews] lastObject];
```

Answer (score 3):

Or like this

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIView *topMost = [window findTopMostViewForPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
```

Functions

```
@implementation UIView (Extra)

- (UIView *)findTopMostViewForPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    for(int i = self.subviews.count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        UIView *subview = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if(!subview.hidden && CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, point))
        {
            CGPoint pointConverted = [self convertPoint:point toView:subview];
            return [subview findTopMostViewForPoint:pointConverted];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isTopmostViewInWindow
{
    if(self.window == nil)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    CGPoint centerPointInSelf = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
    CGPoint centerPointOfSelfInWindow = [self convertPoint:centerPointInSelf toView:self.window];
    UIView *view = [self.window findTopMostViewForPoint:centerPointOfSelfInWindow];
    BOOL isTopMost = view == self || [view isDescendantOfView:self];
    return isTopMost;
}

@end
```